# How to create and get CustomerPaymentProfile in Authorize.Net

Tags: php, payment-gateway, authorize.net

Hello,

I am new at Authorize.net and facing some trouble to integrate it with my **PHP web-site.**

My issues:

1) When i create a customerProfile a payment profile also get created along with it.There is a method to get **customerProfileId($response->getCustomerProfileId()).** But how to get **customerPaymentProfileID**?

2) When i create a **customerPaymentProfile** it is gives success response. but **null** **customerPaymentProfileID**.

3) How to get a list of all **customerPaymentProfiles** by **customerProfileId only.**

I am using same code as provided in Developer API referance in SANDBOX mode

Please help me with this problem guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Authroize.Net
to get customer payment profile ids for a customer profile id, use this sample code :[Sample Code to Get Payment Profile Ids](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-php/blob/master/CustomerProfiles/get-customer-payment-profile-list.php).

And while creating a customer payment profile, it returns a customerPaymentProfile : [API Reference](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#customer-profiles-create-customer-payment-profile),
check the response tab.
For that you need to use `$response->getCustomerPaymentProfileId()`